# Multicast Dropping lots of messages

Tags: android, networking, multicast

I am currently developing a service that runs in an office environment and I am currently trying to leverage UPnP for discovery and management of the service - will be running on between 5 and 45 devices. in testing I am using two Samsung devices running Android 8.0.0.

broadcast address 239.255.255.250
port 1900

I am running Wireshark and am watching all the messages being sent across the network. in my application I am receiving only a few messages and even those are not at the frequency of Wireshark.

```
    while (true)
        {
        try {
            while (true)
                {
                buffer = new byte[1000];
                dp = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                mcSocket.receive(dp);
                String s = new String(dp.getData(), 0, dp.getLength());
                InetAddress ia = dp.getAddress();
                String hostAddress = ia.getHostAddress();
                Log.e(TAG, "index= " + s);

                if (s.contains("upnp:rootMaster"))
                    {
                    System.out.println();
                    }
                }
            }
        catch (IOException ex)
            {
            Logger.getLogger(DLNASearchListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
```

I can see the messages generated by the device I am debugging on, some messages from other devices and on occasionally messages generated by my service running on the other device.

I do run multiple WiFi networks however the both devices are set on the same SSID (this is another question in the future around bridging SSID's).

I have tried a multicast program and it seems to pick up considerable more transmissions.

I have tried WiFi lock and it did not seen to do much good - when set I am not receiving anything.

```
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiManager.MulticastLock multicastLock = wifi.createMulticastLock(masterService);
    multicastLock.setReferenceCounted(true);
    multicastLock.acquire();
```

this should be fairly straight forward but apparently I am missing something.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As a follow-up, I tried this on another couple of devices and it works - now to figure out why one device works perfectly, and the other has such odd behavior

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, but just found on another board that there is a known problem in Android 8 and their multicast support that has been around for a couple of months - considering it is a fundamental component of networking I hope they get it fixed quickly - it is killing the deployment of my service to customers.

Comment: Question is, if we are leveraging UPnP for service discovery, what is a better method?